# Why doesn't the fragment implement the Listener interface?

Tags: android

I have already implemented the DialogListener interface via DialogFragment and NoteFragment

DialogListener

```
interface DialogListener {
    fun onConfirmAddDialogResult(title: String, text: String, date: String, timeStart: String, timeEnd: String)
    fun onScheduleItemDeleted(isDelete: Boolean)
}
```

And so in the Note Fragment, I successfully implemented the interface and did not give out any errors.

```
override fun onConfirmAddDialogResult(
    title: String,
    text: String,
    date: String,
    timeStart: String,
    timeEnd: String
) {
    val data = ScheduleItem(
        text = title,
        description = text,
        date = date,
        startTime = timeStart,
        endTime = timeEnd,
        duration = calculateDuration(timeStart, timeEnd),
        isCompleteTask = false
    )
    viewModel.addData(data)
}
```

In DialogFragment, I made a check for the implementation of the interface and sending data to it.

```
class AddDialogFragment(private val layoutResourceId: Int) : DialogFragment() {
private lateinit var dialogListener: DialogListener
private lateinit var saveButton: ImageButton
private lateinit var cancelButton: ImageButton


override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        dialogListener = parentFragment as DialogListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("Parent fragment must implement DialogListener")
    }
}


private fun handleSaveButtonClicked() {
    dialogListener.onConfirmAddDialogResult(title, text, date, timeStart, timeEnd)
}
}
```

So here is the question itself: why, when trying to implement the interface in the same way as with DialogFragment, an error occurs in BottomSheetDialogFragment, which I have attached below.

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.diarycourse, PID: 13415
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.diarycourse.features.dialogs.DialogListener
at com.example.diarycourse.features.dialogs.ScheduleItemBottomSheetFragment.onAttach(ScheduleItemBottomSheetFragment.kt:40)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3068)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:490)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:265)
.....

If you need how I implement the interface in NoteFragment and interact with it in BottomSheetDialogFragment, then the code below.

Implementation of the interface in NoteFragment:

```
override fun onScheduleItemDeleted(isDelete: Boolean) {
    if (isDelete)
        viewModel.fetchData()
}
```

BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
    class ScheduleItemBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var dialogListener: DialogListener
    @Inject
    lateinit var useCase: UseCase

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        (context.applicationContext as App).appComponent.inject(this)

        try {
            dialogListener = parentFragment as DialogListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException("Parent fragment must implement DialogListener")
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule_item_bottom_sheet, container, false)

      
        val scheduleItem = arguments?.getParcelable<ScheduleItem>("scheduleItem")

        if (scheduleItem != null) {
           ....

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                scheduleItem.id?.let {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val result = useCase.deleteById(it)
                        if (result is Resource.Success) {
                            dialogListener.onScheduleItemDeleted(true)
                            dismiss()
                        } else if (result is Resource.Empty.Failed) {
                            dialogListener.onScheduleItemDeleted(false)
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you showing your dialog? Include that code

Comment: @ianhanniballake I show the dialog when clicking on the fabButton. The function itself is called in onViewCreated in NoteFragment

binding.fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
            AddDialogFragment(R.layout.fragment_add).show(childFragmentManager, "add fragment")
        }

Comment: Your exception is at `ScheduleItemBottomSheetFragment.onAttach`, not `AddDialogFragment`. Where do you show `ScheduleItemBottomSheetFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

**parentFragment** is a nullable type, and

```
private lateinit var dialogListener: DialogListener
```

is a non-null type. This cast type is very dangerous.

I think you should init dialogListener is a nullable type like this:

```
private var dialogListener: DialogListener? = null

private fun handleSaveButtonClicked() {
    dialogListener?.onConfirmAddDialogResult(title, text, date, timeStart, timeEnd)
}
```

Comment: This code is executed normally. The problem with calling the code that is at the very bottom of the question (after the error)